# VBA saving cell address based on contents (doesn't always work)

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to set up a module that copies data from one excel file and pastes it into another. The columns in the copying file will be randomly shuffled and I will need to determine their positions at the start using the code shown below.

My problem here is that I've had the code works sometimes (CopyCell_2 = C1, etc) but also fail sometimes (CopyCell_2 is empty) and I don't know why.

Any insight here would be much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateGroundData()

' Find last row
Dim LastRow_1 As Long      ' Set up variable                                                                       
LastRow_1 = Workbooks("GroundData").Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                ' Find last non-blank row

' Find the right copyranges
With Workbooks("GroundData")
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CopyCell_2 As Variant, CopyCell_3 As Variant, CopyCell_4 As Variant, CopyCell_5 As Variant
    Dim CopyCell_6 As Variant, CopyCell_7 As Variant, CopyCell_8 As Variant, CopyCell_9 As Variant
    For Each cell In Range("C1:J1")
        If InStr(cell.Text, "ADVANCE SPEED") > 0 Then
            CopyCell_2 = cell.Address
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "AMOUNT CENTER FLUSHING") > 0 Then
            CopyCell_3 = cell.Address
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "CUTTIG WHEEL ROTATION SPEED") > 0 Then
            CopyCell_4 = cell.Address
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "DENSITY EXCAVATING CHAMBER") > 0 Then
            CopyCell_5 = cell.Address
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "PRESSURE EXCAVATING CHAMBER 6 (LEFT TOP)") > 0 Then
            CopyCell_6 = cell.Address
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "PRESSURE WORKING CHAMBER") > 0 Then
            CopyCell_7 = cell.Address
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "SHIELD ARTICULATION CONTACT FORCE") > 0 Then
            CopyCell_8 = cell.Address
        ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "TORQUE CUTTING WHEEL") > 0 Then
            CopyCell_9 = cell.Address
        End If
    Next cell
End With
```

EDIT:

Included a pic of GroundData sheet

[image: IMG1]

Comment: There are implicit `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook` references, for starters. The code never references the `With...End With` block, which itself doesn't specify the `Worksheet` - I'm assuming it is the first based on the `LastRow_1` line.

Comment: image of the data would go a long way as it is hard to figure out what is going on here

Comment: @BigBen There will always be only 1 `Worksheet` in that workbook but I'll add that to the `With` block anyway. 
Why does the code not reference the `With` block and any suggestions to make it do so?

Comment: Add a `.` in front of `Range("C1:J1")`, once you've added the `Worksheet` portion to the `With` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mention "*the code works sometimes*," but "*also fails sometimes*," a usual culprit can be unqualified `Range` references, when `ActiveWorkbook` and/or `ActiveSheet` are implied.

In this case, you are not actually using the `With...End With` block, which itself should include a `Worksheet` reference. I'm assuming it would be the first `Worksheet`.
based on the `LastRow_1 = Workbooks("GroundData").Worksheets(1)...` line.

Modify your `With...End With` then to this:

```
With Workbooks("GroundData").Worksheets(1)
    ...
    For Each cell In .Range("C1:J1")
    ...
    Next cell
End With
```

Note that the `.` in front of `Range("C1:J1")` - now its `Workbook` and `Worksheet` are fully qualified and the `With...End With` block is used.

As an additional improvement, you could move the `LastRow_1` line within the `With...End With` since it references the same `Workbook` and `Worksheet`.